# can read, rename and delete but not creating new files or directories

Tags: hard-drive

while i am backing up the data, I am curious as to why that is the only operation that has failed? I have ssd and hdd (Data Disk) and recently my laptop slipped out of my hand. It fell luckily on he left lower corner.

Now i can do all operations on both disks but on the hdd data disk, i can't create files/directories any more but i can rename, delete and read the disk. I can also copy/move from hdd to the ssd but not the vice versa.

Is it a hardware failure or can it be fixed?

Comment: You can use `mount` to see what is mounted (or see `/etc/mtab`). `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -x` will page through the system's log files for the current boot. They will include information about your disks.

Comment: if you are lucky, your harddrive is not plugged in correctly anymore.. If you are not it is a headcrash. This way I lost my old backup drive. and my old ubuntu drive. :(.

Comment: @nobody so i have to open it to check the connection right? or there is a way to see if it is a headcrush? ALso the ssd is well. SO i should replace the hdd with ssd since they seem better then?